# Java Poker Program with if Statement won't output any results

Tags: java, poker

I am completely new to Java and I don't know enough about arrays to do this in a different manner. Can you tell me why nothing will output even when my hand gives me numbers that are next to each other?

```
public class PokerHand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] SUITS = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
    };

    String[] RANKS = {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
    };


    int n = SUITS.length * RANKS.length;
    String[] deck = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
            deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];
        }
    }

    // for statement to randomize output
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
        String temp = deck[r];

        deck[r] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }

    //to output 5 random cards
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
```

//Test for royal flush//////////////////////////////////////

```
        if (RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("Ace")) {

            System.out.println("Royal Flush");

        }
```

//Straight Flush

```
        if (RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5")) {

            System.out.println("Straight flush 1-5");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 2 - 6");


        }
        if (RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 3-7");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 4-8");

        }

        if (RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 5-9");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 6-10");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 7-J");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 8-Q");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 9-K");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("Ace")) {

            System.out.println("Straight Flush 10-Ace");

        }
```

//Four of a kind

```
        if (RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }

        if (RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }

        if (RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King")) {

            System.out.println("Four of a kind");

        }
```

//FULL HOUSE

```
        if (RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }

        if (RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("Ace")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
```

///FLUSH

```
        if (SUITS.equals("Clubs") && SUITS.equals("Clubs") && SUITS.equals("Clubs") && SUITS.equals("Clubs") && SUITS.equals("Clubs")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (SUITS.equals("Diamonds") && SUITS.equals("Diamonds") && SUITS.equals("Diamonds") && SUITS.equals("Diamonds") && SUITS.equals("Diamonds")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (SUITS.equals("Hearts") && SUITS.equals("Hearts") && SUITS.equals("Hearts") && SUITS.equals("Hearts") && SUITS.equals("Hearts")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }
        if (SUITS.equals("Spades") && SUITS.equals("Spades") && SUITS.equals("Spades") && SUITS.equals("Spades") && SUITS.equals("Spades")) {

            System.out.println("Full House");

        }


        //STRAIGHT



        if (RANKS.equals("Ace") && RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5")) {

            System.out.println("Straight ");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("2") && RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");


        }
        if (RANKS.equals("3") && RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("4") && RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8")) {

            System.out.println("Straight ");

        }

        if (RANKS.equals("5") && RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("6") && RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("7") && RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("8") && RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("9") && RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King")) {

            System.out.println("Straight");

        }
        if (RANKS.equals("10") && RANKS.equals("Jack") && RANKS.equals("Queen") && RANKS.equals("King") && RANKS.equals("Ace")) {

            System.out.println("Straight ");

        }

        //Three of a kind

        if (deck.equals("Ace"))

            System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("2")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }

    if (deck.equals("3")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }

    if (deck.equals("4"))

    {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("5")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("6")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("7")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("8")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("9")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("10")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("Jack")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("Queen")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
    if (deck.equals("King")) {

        System.out.println("TOAK");

    }
```

//Two Pairs
        if (deck.equals("Ace") && deck.equals("2")) {

```
        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("Ace") && deck.equals("2")) {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }

    //One Pair


    if (deck.equals("Ace") && deck.equals("Ace"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("2") && deck.equals("2"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("3") && deck.equals("3"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("4") && deck.equals("4"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("5") && deck.equals("5"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("6") && deck.equals("6"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("7") && deck.equals("7"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("8") && deck.equals("8"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("9") && deck.equals("9"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("10") && deck.equals("10"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("Jack") && deck.equals("Jack"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("Queen") && deck.equals("Queen"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");

    }
    if (deck.equals("King") && deck.equals("King"))

    {

        System.out.println("TP");


    }

  //NO PAIR



}
```

}

Comment: The output of code you provided is (https://ideone.com/o3HaD50): `8 of Hearts
Ace of Hearts
5 of Clubs
8 of Diamonds
7 of Hearts
` What do you mean there is no output?

Comment: I am sorry I meant there's not output from my ifStatements I just need someone to point out my error, thank you. (No matter what 5 cards I get.)

Comment: The conditions in the of statements make no sense. You are comparing an array 8entire array object) with some string literal. -- You'll have to redesign your program around a class Card with fields rank and suit and analyse a hand by looking at the properties of 5 such objects.

Comment: so there is no way for the ifstatements to evaluate my hand? thanks in advance.

Comment: Not those if statements. You're just comparing something with itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand, you are comparing an entire array with an `String`. This will *never* result on anything. To make this work, you will need to compare an item of an array.

For example, you have an array `String[] handRanks`, and you want to know if you have some rank in some position of this array, so you can create an method that uses an `for` loop to check *every* position of the array, like this:

```java
public boolean hasRank(String rank) {
    for(int i = 0; i < handRanks.length; i++) {
        if(handRanks[i].equals(rank)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you will can do the royal flush test, for example:

```java
if(hasRank("Jack") && hasRank("10") && hasRank("Queen") && hasRank("King") && hasRank("Ace")) {
    System.out.println("Royal flush find!");
}
```